# How do I add a vertical line to a plotly gantt chart using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataset with columns `Task` (`string` type),`Period_Min` and `Period_Max`. I would like to plot a classic gantt chart using `plotly` and add a vertical line for the special day `2017-12-31`.

I've already tried the basic way to do it accordinf to plotly's official [doc](https://plot.ly/python/shapes/).

Here is my code:

```
fig=ff.create_gantt(data_user1,colors['#333F44','#93e4c1'],index_col='Diff_temps')
layout = {
'shapes': [
    # Line Vertical
    {
        'type': 'line',
        'x0': '2017-12-31',
        'y0': data_user1.Task.values[0],
        'x1': '2017-12-31',
        'y1': data_user1.Task.tail(1).values[0],
        'line': {
            'color': 'rgb(55, 128, 191)',
            'width': 3,
        }
    }
]
}

iplot(fig, layout)
```

Unfortunately, adding this particular **layout** doesn't change anything in my chart. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The tips provided in this [Plotly community post](https://community.plot.ly/t/milestones-on-gantt-charts/5864/4) might be helpful here.

Give this a try:

```
fig = ff.create_gantt(data_user1, colors['#333F44','#93e4c1'], index_col='Diff_temps')

shapes = [
    # Line Vertical
    {
        'type': 'line',
        'x0': '2017-12-31',
        'y0': data_user1.Task.values[0],
        'x1': '2017-12-31',
        'y1': data_user1.Task.tail(1).values[0],
        'line': {
            'color': 'rgb(55, 128, 191)',
            'width': 3,
        }
    }
]
fig['layout']['shapes'] += shapes

iplot(fig, layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was looking to do the same thing and couldn't find an answer that worked for me. The [Plotly community post](https://community.plot.ly/t/milestones-on-gantt-charts/5864/4) that [roborative](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711105/roborative) mentioned didn’t contain an answer that worked for me either. But after some experimenting I found a solution that works:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig=ff.create_gantt(data_user1,colors['#333F44','#93e4c1'],index_col='Diff_temps')

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = ['2017-12-31', '2017-12-31'],
        y = [-1, len(data_user1.index) + 1],
        mode = "lines",
        line = go.scatter.Line(color = "gray", width = 1),
        showlegend = False
    )
)

fig.show()
```

This assumes that `data_user1` is a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing. Were you able to fix your issue with this or not?

Comment: After rereading my answer I understand that the wording was a little confusing. I edited it and hope that it’s now clear that this fixed the issue for me.